# CSS fails to act on a div class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why my css is not working on the .build class divs. I have no idea where i went wrong. 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <title> Build Projects

    (bryan22)

    </title>
<link href = 'obpstyle.css' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Build Projects </h1>   
    <strong> bryan22 </strong>
    <a class = 'navbut' href = 'index2.php'>Home</a>
    <a class = 'navbut' href = 'obpmembers.php'>Members</a>
    <a class = 'navbut' href = 'obpfriends.php'>Friends</a>
    <a class = 'navbut' href = 'obpmessages.php'>Messages</a>
    <a class = 'navbut' href = 'obpmembers.php?view=bryan22'>Profile</a>
    <a class = 'navbut' href = 'obpbrowse.php'>Browse Builds</a> 
    <a class = 'navbut' href = 'obplogout.php'>Log Out</a>

    <div class = 'showProfile'> <h3 class = 'heading'>Your Page</h3>
        <div id = 'profimg'>
            <img src = '../website/users/bryan22/bryan22.jpg' />
        </div>
        <p class = 'usertext'>
            I'm Bryan!
        </p>
        <form action = '' method = 'post'>
            <input type = 'submit' name = 'edit' value = 'Edit' />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class = 'builds'>
        <a href = 'obpbuilds.php?view=bryan22&build=The Danger Ranger'>
            <strong>The Danger Ranger</strong>
            <br />
        </a>
<img src = '../website/users/bryan22/The Danger Ranger/The Danger Ranger.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div class = 'builds'>
        <a href = 'obpbuilds.php?view=bryan22&build=450 monster'>
            <strong>450 monster</strong>
            <br />
        </a>
    <img src = '../website/users/bryan22/450 monster/450 monster.jpg' />
    </div>
    <a href = 'obpmessages.php?view=bryan22'> Your Messages</a> 
    <a href = 'obpfriends.php?view=bryan22'> Your Friends</a></body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.builds
{
float:right; !important;
font-family:helvetica;
background-color:red !important;
}
.showProfile
{
/*float:left;*/
background-color:red
}
```

i really just want the build divs to float next to the showProfile div, but not even the background color is working. Please give me some insight. 
thanks!

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/9KC2S/?

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work" ?

Comment: Can you throw that into a http://jsfiddle.net/ and show us what is happening?  And be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry i missed the semi-colon. But that's not the problem. When i say doesn't work, i mean no matter what i put in there (background-color:red;) nothing happens.

Comment: Musa, did you change any of the code when you put it in there? if not, then yes, i would like for that to happen, but it's not happening on my page. im puzzled.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me?

Comment: He changed     background-color:red!important; to     background-color:green!important; Also it's bad practice to use !important unless you really have to.

Comment: I was just using !important to see if it would work, to no avail.

Comment: He also removed <div><div class = 'builds'>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FgNYs/2/  that is how i'd like it to look, it works fine on jsfiddle, but not on my page. Would having the php function creating the 'builds' divs help?

Comment: If possible use id="builds" instead of class and try

Comment: If it works fine in the fiddle.. there there's some other code causing a problem. perhaps something else in the stylesheet. There should be no issue with having a PHP loop spitting out divs with classes applied. DO NOT use an ID as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks scott! There is something in the stylesheet, havent pin pointed it yet, but you were right on the money. Thanks a million!

Comment: My problem was having selectors without declaration blocks, apparently that doesn't work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no issue with a PHP loop creating divs with applied classes. The CSS should be picked up and used for each iteration of the loop.

If the HTML/CSS is working properly in your fiddle, as you've commented, then there must be some other issue with either the HTML, CSS, or PHP which is causing the code to be malformed or superseded.

Comment: thanks again for your insight Scott. just a rookie mistake. wish i could vote you up, but i don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score -1):

I made a simple layout for you. Hope this is what you are looking for: [codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/KEbzd).

Comment: the 'builds' divs are created dynamically by my php. there will be one for each photo in the album.